# Calculate Percentage with T-SQL statement while using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In working through the AdventureWorks2012 database for Microsoft SQL Server 2012 in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167154.aspx) part of the tutorial, I wanted to add to the example and find out how use a variation of this query:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate) AS 'Days Late',
    COUNT(WorkOrderID) AS 'Late Orders',
    (COUNT(WorkOrderID) / SUM(COUNT(WorkOrderID)) AS '% of Late Orders'
 FROM Production.WorkOrder
 WHERE DueDate < EndDate
 GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate)
 ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate);
```

To make this table where '% of Late Orders' gives the count which was late by a certain number of days and divides it by all orders that were late, it should look like the following:

```
----------------------------------------
|Days Late|Late Orders|% of Late Orders|
----------------------------------------
|21       |784        |10              |
|18       |1285       |14              |
----------------------------------------
```

I've tried several variations of this query, viewed several related StackOverflow questions, but cannot get this table to work without receiving error messages. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111153/t-sql-calculate-percentage) question got me closest but the results were off.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What SQL did you try, and what were the error messages you received?

Comment: @BillGregg T-SQL, Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate) AS 'Days Late',
COUNT(WorkOrderID) AS 'Late Orders',
(COUNT(WorkOrderID)*1.0 / (select count(1) as TotalLateOrders FROM Production.WorkOrder
WHERE DueDate < EndDate))
AS '% of Late Orders'
FROM Production.WorkOrder
WHERE DueDate < EndDate
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate)
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate);
```

I'm multiplying by 1.0 to divide with floats, you can do this on the previous answer too

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that since you are using a `GROUP BY` statement, *all* of your aggregate functions are operating over your subgroups.  You will need to separately calculate the value for "all orders that were late" in order to get the value over all late orders instead of all late orders with a given lateness, likely using a CTE.

Perhaps something like this:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

;WITH late (num_late_orders)
AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(WorkOrderID)
    FROM Production.WorkOrder
    WHERE DueDate < EndDate
)
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate) AS 'Days Late',
    COUNT(WorkOrderID) AS 'Late Orders',
    (CAST(COUNT(WorkOrderID) AS decimal(14, 3)) / CAST(MAX(late.num_late_orders) AS decimal(14, 3))) AS '% of Late Orders'
FROM Production.WorkOrder
    CROSS JOIN late
WHERE DueDate < EndDate
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate)
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd,DueDate,EndDate);
```

You might be confused as to why I have `MAX()` around `late.num_late_orders`.  The reason is that since the value is not included in the `GROUP BY` clause, it has to be included in an aggregate statement, even though the value is constant over the entire query.

Comment: This could very well be something that is my fault, but when implementing your solution '% of Late Orders' were returned as 0 for each of the rows. Do you how that could have happened? Thanks!

Comment: That should only happen if `COUNT(WorkOrderID)` was 0 for each row.  What were your values for 'Late Orders' for those rows?  You could also add `MAX(late.num_late_orders)` as an additional column to see what those values are.

Comment: The values for Late Orders [Days Late, Late Orders, % of Late Orders] are (1, 2656, 0), (3, 2736, 0), (3, 2736, 0), etc. When I add MAX(late.num_late_orders) as an additional column then the following is returned, (1, 2656, 0, 22790), (3, 2736, 0, 22790), (3, 2736, 0, 22790), etc.

Comment: You're getting 0 because it's doing integer division and the results are less than zero.  You need to cast your numbers as decimals before doing the division.